# SharePoint Calculated formula to display quartery week

Tags: share

I am trying to create a field when a date is entered it will display the correct week within the quarter. New to sharepoint and have had no luck finding this. I found a formula to display the Fiscal week but need the quarterly week broken out. Week 1-13

Comment: Can you give a sample of expected output? It is like `F(2016-02-20) = Q1-W7`?

Comment: When you enter a date into the list it will populated a calculated field with the corresponding week in the quarter would like it to show as W01, W02, etc

Comment: I assume you're using ISO-8601. I'm pretty sure we can find a formula together, but I'll need some help understanding the requirement here. What it should show for these particular dates: 03-Jan-16; 04-Jan-16; 01-Apr-16?

Comment: our Q1 actually begins February 1st, 2/1/2016 W01
2/2/2016 W01
2/3/2016 W01
2/4/2016 W01
2/5/2016 W01
2/6/2016 W02
2/7/2016 W02
2/8/2016 W02
2/9/2016 W02
2/10/2016 W02
2/11/2016 W02
2/12/2016 W02
2/13/2016 W03
2/14/2016 W03
2/15/2016 W03
2/16/2016 W03
2/17/2016 W03
2/18/2016 W03
2/19/2016 W03
2/20/2016 W04
2/21/2016 W04
2/22/2016 W04
2/23/2016 W04
2/24/2016 W04
2/25/2016 W04
2/26/2016 W04
2/27/2016 W05
2/28/2016 W05
2/29/2016 W05

Comment: Ok, I got the idea. Can you confirm: 29-Apr-16 is W13, 30-Apr-16 is W01

Comment: That is correct 29 Apr - W13 and 30th April is W01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You said Q1 starts February 1st*. Try this formula:

`="W"&TEXT(ROUNDDOWN((([Column1]-42401+2)/7)+1;0)-ROUNDDOWN(ROUNDDOWN((([Column1]-42401+2)/7)+1;0)/13;0)*13+IF(ROUNDDOWN((([Column1]-42401+2)/7)+1;0)-ROUNDDOWN(ROUNDDOWN((([Column1]-42401+2)/7)+1;0)/13;0)*13=0;13;0);"00")`

It only uses functions mentioned at least once in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx : `TEXT`, `ROUNDDOWN` and `IF`.

You might need to replace semicolons with commas depending on your regional settings.

---

Update: `42401` here is hard-coded value for February 1st, 2016. +2 part is offset also specific to year 2016. For other years you'll need to modify accordingly. `42401` could be replaced with `=DATE(YEAR([Column1]);2;1)`

Comment: Aziz, thank you for your help with this, I do appreciate it. I tried the above formula and it worked! for week 3 it is showing with a dash W-03 all others are showing as W02 without a dash. Is there something I need to modify? Again I very much appreciate all your help.

Comment: @KrisMaxymof That's strange. Please double check your dates, there's nothing special in week 3. Can you paste this formula to Excel and check if it works fine for W03 there?

Comment: thank you, I will double check to see if it has something to do with my date. I can not thank you enough for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @I've added some details. PS: offset could be turned to function of [Column1] too, but it'll get much uglier. And it's already the ugliest formula I've managed to write in SP :) Good luck

Comment: @KrisMaxymof sure, my pleasure. Mind to close this question so anyone in future could find the solution that worked for you and maybe adapt?

Comment: Closed the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Just thinking out loud...*

For Q2-Q3 you need to substract the last date of the previous Quarter so you can use the Fiscal week function.... *maybe?*

It is going to be a long (complex) Formula, make it work in Excel first

Last date of Q3 would be: **October 1st minus 1 day**

```
 =DATE( YEAR(Created) , 10 , 1 ) - 1
```